# Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick) /dev/bus/usb non-root ioctl denied

Tags: ubuntu

Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick).

I have a problem running the program garmin_save_runs (part of the garmin-forerunner-tools package) as an ordinary user, whereas it works when run with sudo. Non-sudo execution used to work under Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid), and I think the package has not changed very much, so I guess some permissions have changed with the upgrade.

I found out I can work around having to run the program as sudo:
$ sudo setcap CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE=ep /usr/bin/garmin_save_runs

Now I'm wondering:

1. What has changed from Lucid to Maverick to cause this issue?
2. Is my setcap solution a good one?
3. Is the program at fault?

strace excerpt:

```
open("/dev/bus/usb/001/010", O_RDWR)    = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
open("/dev/bus/usb/001/010", O_RDONLY)  = 3
ioctl(3, USBDEVFS_IOCTL or USBDEVFS_IOCTL32, 0x7ffffabef170) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
close(3)                                = 0
open("/dev/bus/usb/001/002", O_RDWR)    = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
open("/dev/bus/usb/001/002", O_RDONLY)  = 3
ioctl(3, USBDEVFS_IOCTL or USBDEVFS_IOCTL32, 0x7ffffabef170) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
close(3)                                = 0
open("/dev/bus/usb/001/001", O_RDWR)    = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
open("/dev/bus/usb/001/001", O_RDONLY)  = 3
ioctl(3, USBDEVFS_IOCTL or USBDEVFS_IOCTL32, 0x7ffffabef170) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
close(3)                                = 0
```

Comment: Sounds like you don't have permission to touch the USB device as normal user.